# SQL syntax error for GRANT ALL statement only with mysql -e --execute

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

mysql tells me i have an SQL syntax error when using this statement on my ubuntu shell

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "GRANT ALL ON `mydb`.* to 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypwd';"
```

i also tried this syntax:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "GRANT ALL ON `mydb`.* to 'myuser@%' identified by 'mypwd';"
```

afaik i have no funny hidden characters in there, when i execute the statement within the mysql client it works fine. Is there anything i am missing?

example error message

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* to 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypwd'' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem. The character used to escape the database name is responsible for the syntax error. This statement without them works fine

```
mysql -uroot -proot -e "GRANT ALL ON mydb.* to 'myuser@%' identified by 'mypwd';"
```

i know little about shell commands but i guess the "`" character does something funny. Maybe someone with more experience cares to explain (- : and how one can escape it to prevent such errors